# Unprotect MS-Word document (protected with a password) in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I am looking to compare 2 MS-Word documents. But for docs that are protected I need to unprotect/unlock them with the password. For now, I am able to get the protection level of a word doc in Java. The following code works for both doc and docx.

```
public static void getDocProtectionLevelV2(String fileName) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    XWPFDocument document       = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("    DEBUG : fileName : " + fileName);
    System.out.println("        DEBUG : document.isEnforcedCommentsProtection() :       " + document.isEnforcedCommentsProtection());           
    System.out.println("        DEBUG : document.isEnforcedFillingFormsProtection() :   " + document.isEnforcedFillingFormsProtection());           
    System.out.println("        DEBUG : document.isEnforcedReadonlyProtection() :       " + document.isEnforcedReadonlyProtection());
    System.out.println("        DEBUG : document.isEnforcedTrackedChangesProtection() : " + document.isEnforcedTrackedChangesProtection());        
    System.out.println("        DEBUG : document.isEnforcedUpdateFields() :             " + document.isEnforcedUpdateFields());        
}
```

Buw I am unable to find a way to unprotect/unlock the word file (both doc and docx).